# Adding FB Activities to an HTML Webpage

Tags: html, facebook

I'm trying to get Facebook Posts, Events, etc to appear on a Webpage.  An active newsfeed area to appear on the website.

Basically want whatever is posted on this Facebook page: [TheRestaurantChannelnet](https://www.facebook.com/TheRestaurantChannelnet)

To show up in a newsfeed at the bottom of this webpage: http://www.therestaurantchannel.net/restaurantchanneltv.html

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I've tried several options. You can see on the webpage already at the bottom I've manually added a "post" which isn't want I want, and tried adding "activity" but nothing shows up, and added "comments" area.

Here is what i tried-

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 

<script>
  (function(d, s, id) 
  { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); 
  js.id = id; 
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=202873143214457";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: You will need to look into the Facebook API. This is too broad a question to answer in its present state. Check out this [LINK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/) and the tutorials that go along with it. Hopefully it helps

Comment: I'm still learning how to do all this stuff, and not super strong with HTML and coding.  Basically I want the Facebook Wall stuff to appear on a webpage.  I used this code in the body tag:<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=202873143214457";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

Comment: And this code in the table:

Comment: <div class="fb-activity" data-site="https://www.facebook.com/TheRestaurantChannelnet" data-action="like,comment" data-width="300" align="center" data-height="300" data-header="true" data-colorscheme="dark" data-font="tahoma" data-recommendations="true" ></div>

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=Your App ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

You need to Have one app before you can use this.